# How would one enumerate relations that are transitive but not symmetric?

Tags: combinatorics

Of late, I have been trying to enumerate various types of relations on a set. Counting transitive relations seems very hard. However, it is known that the number of relations on an n-element set that are both transitive and symmetric is equal to the number of equivalence relations on an n+1-element set. This brings me to the following question:

How would one enumerate relations that are transitive but not symmetric?

Comment: Count the transitive relations and subtract the number of symmetric transitive relations.

Comment: How would you count the number the transitive relations?

Comment: I don't know. Seems very hard, like you said. But imposing the condition "not symmetric" is hardly going to make it any easier. Counting non-symmetric transitive relations seems even more complicated than counting transitive relations. I could be wrong. Do you have some reason to think it won't be?

Comment: Counting by hand I get $171$ transitive relations for $n=3$, which agrees with http://oeis.org/A006905. Subtracting $15$ symmetric transitive relations I get $156$ non-symmetric transitive relations.

Comment: The number of symmetric transitive relations on a $3$-element set is the same as the namber of equivalence relations on a $4$-element set, which is the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_4=15$: $1$ with $1$ equivalence class, $7$ with $2$ equivalence classes, $6$ with $3$ equivalence classes, $1$ with $4$ equivalence classes.

Comment: Yes. Seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple application of the recursive relation on Bell numbers.

Try using $B_{n+1}=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}B_r$.

Comment: But the OP said *not* symmetric.